# JSON result not getting in AJAX

Tags: android, json, cordova

The `JSON` didn't give correct result(issuccess:failed)  on `AJAX` while it give correct result in postman(issuccess:true)

The `JSON` response in `AJAX`

[image: image1]

and

The `JSON` result in postman

[image: image 2]

```
                            var jData = {};
                            jData.username = $scope.mobile;
                            jData.password = $scope.password;
                            jData.entrytoken="aaad1323dfd";

                            var $resData = null; 
                            $.ajax({
                                url:url,
                                type: "POST",
                                ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data:JSON.stringify(jData) ,         
                                dataType: "json",
                                beforeSend: function () { 

                                  },
                              success: function (response) {

                               console.log(response);
                               },
                             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

                                  },
                      complete: function () {

                               }
                          });
```

Comment: Have you try change `ContentType` to `contentType` (lower `c`), or just remove `ContentType`

Comment: no change in result

Comment: Maybe you can click the `code` under `Save` button in postman, to see the Ajax sample and compare with your code, it's pretty hard to answer without knowing what you sending out from your postman

Comment: Well, have you checked what error the server throws? Basic diagnosis is missing here. Show us exactly what you send in Postman, what the status and message of the response is in both cases. People on SO can't guess all these details for you.